# how to display nested data structure with table in angularjs 2.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular2-template, ngfor

I have a data structure as below:

    `testResults: {
        children: [
            {
                type: "testGroup",
                name: "group-1",
                result: "pass"
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "testGroup", // nested test group
                        name: "group-1-1",
                        result: "pass",
                        children: [
                            {
                                type: "testCase",
                                name: "case-1-1-1",
                                result: "pass",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        type: "testBlock",
                                        name: "testblock-1-1-1-1",
                                        result: "pass"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        type: "testBlock",
                                        name: "testblock-1-1-1-2",
                                        result: "pass"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }`

Test group can be nested for many levels. eg:

-test group 1

---child test group 1-1

-----child child test group 1-1-1

-------child child child test group 1-1-1-1

---------test case 1-1-1-1-1

-----------test block 1-1-1-1-1-1

Please note that the number of nested group vary.

And I want to display this data structure in a table as below:
[image]

**Is it possible to get it done in angularjs 2.0 without writing any js code?**

Without js code, I mean just use angularjs 2.0 directive (eg. ngFor.).

I've tried using ngFor as below, but it will mess up the DOM structure:

    `<tr *ngFor="let item of data.testResults.children; let i = index">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.result}}</td>
        <div *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0">
            <tr *ngFor="let s1 of item.children; let i1 = index ">
                <td>{{s1.name}}</td>
                <td>{{s1.result}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tr>`

Even the code above works, I still don't know how many nested ngFor directives should be used.

**So I'm wondering is there any equivalent of WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate and DataTemplate in angularjs 2.0?**

Comment: It is not clear what the result should look like. Please explain.

Comment: A good starting point would be the HTML markup you want to arrive at. That would be much clearer than just a screenshot...